If $P(X=Y)=1$, $Z$ is independent of $X$, is $Z$ independent of $Y$?
Intuitively, I would like to give a negative answer to this question. I tried to construct an example:
Let $X(\omega) \equiv 0$, $Y(\omega) = 0+Z(\omega_0)I\{\omega =\omega_0 \}$. $X,Y$ share the same probability space. It seems to give an counterexample to this question, but I found it hard to strictly illustrate that $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

The answer is YES. Just apply the definition of independence.

$P(Y<y,Z<z) \neq P(X<y, Z<z)$ @geetha290krm

There's a small technical trick and you need to do it in two steps.
Consider any two Borel sets $A$ and $B$,
Then \begin{align}P(Y\in A,Z\in B)&=P(Y\in A,Z\in B, X=Y)+P(Y\in A,Z\in B,X\neq Y)\\
&=P(X\in A, Z\in B,X=Y)\end{align}
as $P(Y\in A,Z\in B,X\neq Y)\leq P(X\neq Y)=0$
Now see that \begin{align}P(X\in A,Z\in B)&=P(X\in A, Z\in B, X=Y)+P(X\in A,Z\in B,X\neq Y)\\
&=P(X\in A,Z\in B,X=Y)\end{align}
as again $P(X\in A,Z\in B,X\neq Y)\leq P(X\neq Y)=0$
So combining both equations, you have $P(Y\in A,Z\in B)=P(X\in A,Z\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Z\in B)$ due to independence of $X$ and $Z$.
Now  $$P(X\in A)=P(Y\in A, X=Y)+P(X\in A,X\neq Y)=P(Y\in A,X=Y)$$ and $$P(Y\in A)=P(Y\in A,X=Y)+P(Y\in A,X\neq Y)=P(Y\in A,X=Y)$$
Thus $P(X\in A)=P(Y\in A)$
Combining all of the above, you get $P(Y\in A,Z\in B)=P(Y\in A)P(Z\in B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$. Thus $Y$ is independent of $Z$.
If you take $A=(-\infty,y]$ and $B=(-\infty,z]$, then you get $F(y,z)=F_{Y}(y)F_{Z}(z)$ and hence the joint CDF factorizes into the product of marginal cdf's which also is enough to prove independence.
Note: Essentially what we are doing is applying the result that if $E$ and $F$ are two events such that $P(F)=1$, then $P(E)=P(E\cap F)$

Thank you for your detailed answer and I have learned a lot from this!
